# When I query a partitioned table, is it possible to filter by partition column with a subquery and reduce cost at the same time?

Tags: google-bigquery

I can see from public documentation that BigQuery partition table has this [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables) that if the partition column has a subquery as a filter, it won't prune the queried partition and reduce "bytes processed"(cost). I'm wondering if there is a way to workaround.

For example, this query will scan 38.67 GB, is there a way to reduce it?

```sql
WITH sub_query_that_generates_filter AS (
  SELECT DATE "2016-10-01" as month UNION ALL
  SELECT "2017-10-01" UNION ALL
  SELECT "2018-10-01"
)
SELECT block_hash, fee FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions`
WHERE block_timestamp_month in 
(SELECT month FROM sub_query_that_generates_filter)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With BigQuery [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting), there is a way to reduce the cost.

Basically, a scripting variable is defined to capture the dynamic part of a subquery. Then in subsequent query, scripting variable is used as a filter to prune the partitions to be scanned.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sub_query_that_generates_filter AS (
  SELECT DATE "2017-10-01" as month UNION ALL
  SELECT "2018-10-01" UNION ALL
  SELECT "2016-10-01" 
);
BEGIN
  DECLARE month_filter ARRAY<DATE> 
    DEFAULT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(month) FROM sub_query_that_generates_filter);

  SELECT block_hash, fee FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions` 
    WHERE block_timestamp_month in UNNEST(month_filter);
END
```

It scans only 2GB of data instead of 38GB. Cheaper and faster!

[image]